# What are these burnt-like spots on my potato leaf?

Tags: vegetables, containers, potatoes

[image]
[image]

I planted some Russian Blue potato's (next to some tomatoes I might add) and noticed what I think might be sun damage. However I wanted to confirm, perhaps it's some like alternaria. I also wanted to know whether I should worry about this hopping to my tomato, thanks all!